# How to remove specific documents from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

Trying to remove specific chats from a Mongo collection.

**Sample Chat in MongoDB:**

```
{ "_id" : "4jkq6fJbNtwEGxTzv", "user1Id" : "czA8espdEbTgz7HqG", "user2Id" : "WyvyFaAdGqEKJgcni", "messages" : [ { "timeStamp" : "Wed, 09 Nov 2016 06:19:08 GMT", "sentBy" : "czA8espdEbTgz7HqG", "text" : "testing123" } ] }
```

**Tried:**

```
db.chat_users.remove( {"_id": ObjectId("4jkq6fJbNtwEGxTzv")});
```

**But got:**

```
Error: invalid object id: length
```

**Tried:**

```
db.user_track.remove( { access_time : {"$lt" : new Date(2016, 12, 1) } })
```

**But got:**

```
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })
```

Option 1: Why are my object ID's too short?

Option 2: Why weren't chats created before December 1 removed?

Any ideas how I can remove a bunch of chats from Wed, 09 Nov 2016?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your `id` class is not ObjectId! mongo stores a normal ObjectId like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("583aca7d7882395095bef1fc")
```

So change your code to this:

```
db.chat_users.remove( {"_id": "4jkq6fJbNtwEGxTzv"});
```

Comment: Thanks Moshsen89z. It works. I accepted your answer. It is not publicly shown but is recorded.